# ¿Se puede contar el número de columnas de un datarow en c#?

Tags: c#, .net

Estoy realizando un programa en C#, y tengo que pasar los registros a un StringBuilder.

```
public static string GenerarTF(Balanza oBalanza, String direccionLogica,String grupo, DataRow dtFuente, LogApp oLog) {
            StringBuilder sbRowFuente = new StringBuilder();
            if(dtFuente != null){

            }
```

El problema es que cada registro tiene multitud de campos (columnas), y sería mejor recorrer en bucle el datarow e insertar los valores al stringbuilder. No logro poder contar las columnas del datarow. ¿Alguien sabe hacerlo? Gracias

Comment: ¿Has probado `dtFuente.Rows.Count` ó `dtFuente.Rows.Length`?

Comment: `dtFuente.Columns.Count()` es lo que buscas

Answer (score 3):

Si sólo necesitas el número de columnas, lo puedes extraer a través de la Tabla asociada a la fila

```
dtFuente.Table.Columns.Count
```

Comment: Eso era lo que estaba buscando. Gracias y un saludo